# Which Ubuntu Flavor is best for old PC WITH Nvidia GeForce 6150SE nForce 430 and AMD 64Bit and 4 GB Ram?

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I had horrible experience installing Ubuntu on my machine with Nvidia. Just want to hear some expert advice. Currently using Linux Mint but want to switch back to any Ubuntu flavor, just not sure which is best.

Comment: Is this a laptop?  Cooling the 6150 chip is pretty iffy in some laptops with the unity desktop.

Comment: It's a desktop but you're right, Unity is very resource hungry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably best if you use Lubuntu or Xubuntu, which both use lightweight desktop environments. Make sure you use the proprietary nvidia drivers, as there are [known issues](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=140397) with running `nouveau` drivers on this device. Other good options include Peppermint, Puppy, Crunchbang (now deceased but there are forks). You may even wish to run Unity2D.

(I recommended these other distributions mainly because you asked for an *Ubuntu* based distribution, which probably means you're most familiar with the `apt` package management)

Comment: Thanks codingman, I decided to switch to Lubuntu. Peppermint is okay but I like to have a "traditional" (aka old-fashioned) desktop.

Comment: Great that that's working for ya! If I helped you, it'd be great if you could accept my answer :)